# Google Sheets - IF cell is EQUAL TO AND IS NOT BLANK

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

forgot my old login, new account.

I'm asking the sheet to pull a value from CF2:CF30 based on values in CE2:CE30

But there are 3 conditions in D3, two of which should result in 0, and one to produce the value in CF2:CF30

I managed that, below.

`=IF(D3="PT",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3, $CE$2:$CF$30, 2, FALSE), ""),0)`

Now I'm out of my depth.

I just realised if there is no value at all D3 I'd like the target cell to remain blank rather than produce a 0 value.

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

I've googled ISBLANK and tried to integrate it unsuccessfully.

Checked some related questions and cant figure out how to implement the solution into this formula.

Comment: IF(D3="","",IF(D3="PT",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3, $CE$2:$CF$30, 2, FALSE), ""),0))

Comment: Thanks heaps Mike, can't believe it was that simple.
Legend.